# Source of do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm receiving an error message:

`Error: [vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.`

Which I understand means I'm mutating state outside of where I should be. However, my project is large enough that I'm having difficulty finding the file or line where this is occurring. The error message says it is stemming from `client.js` which is not a file I have made (I assume that Nuxt builds my code into this `client.js` file). Screenshot shown below:

[image]

My question is, how can I diagnose where this error is occurring when the error reporting is so vague?

Comment: I imagine `index.cjs.js` is your bundled code, click on it in the stack trace and see if you recognize the line.

Comment: I don't recognize anything in that file at all, unfortunately

Comment: It can be something like `state.bananas = oranges` in an action that can cause this. You could try and match what mutations are happening when in dev tools with when the error occurs - but yeah it can be tough to pin down things like this - but search for any `state.something = ...` or `this.$store.state.something = ...` or something along those lines